# separate vertical alignment in column layout with css table cells

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a three-column layout using `aside`s and an `article` with `display: table-cell` inside a `section`.

The problem is that any text in one column aligns with the bottom of the line with the text in another column.

This simplified code shows what I mean:

CSS:

```
section {
    display: table;
}
aside, article {
    display:table-cell;
}
aside>header {
    font-size: 50px;
}
article>header {
    font-size: 100px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<section>
    <aside>
        <header>Text1</header>
    </aside>
    <article>
        <header>Text2</header>
    </article>
</section>
```

And a jsfiddle which shows the result:
http://jsfiddle.net/martenkoetsier/Ja3sW/

(I have used a two-column layout here to simplify)

The first column has a text in a "small" font and the second column has a text in a "big" font. What happens, is that the two lines of text align with their respective baselines to each other (tested in Opera and Firefox).

I understand that this may be desired behavior in normal tables and that this might be a hint to not using even CSS tables for layout. However, the use of floats still causes too much trouble to get it right (as confirmed by many blog posts on the subject).

I would like the *top* of the text (or whatever content) to be at the *top* of the column, even if any other column has a different font size. The alignment should be completely separate between columns.

I have tried the `vertical-align: top` property, but that doesn't do the job.

What am I missing? I am looking for a solution that works in the major browsers and IE 8 and above.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure http://jsfiddle.net/Ja3sW/3/?

Comment: If you mean the text aligning each other to top...well the `line-height` default changes base on the font size

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I just accepted the answer from ced-b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a `vertical-align: top` to the `aside, article` does it for me. If that does not work in all browsers for whatever reason you could also switch the `display` from `table-cell` to `inline-block`.

See http://jsfiddle.net/Ja3sW/4/ (vertical-align:top) and http://jsfiddle.net/Ja3sW/5/ (inline-block)

Comment: Wow, didn't see that one coming: I just plainly put the vertical-align in the _wrong_ element! Thanks a ton!

Comment: Your welcome. Please make sure to accept the answer.